# How to create testruns in polarion if there's no testruns page in my project?

Tags: polarion

So, I'm using the 30 day polarion trial. 
If I go to the left navigation panel there should be a shortcut that would take me to a page named "testruns". In this page I should be able to create testruns but the page doesn't even exist! 
Is there a way to create this page? I've aready looked into the polarion instructional videos but since the page does not exist I cannot follow them properly. Thanks in advance!

I've already looked for polarion tutorials on the web but I need to have the "testruns" page beforehand.
I haven't been able to copy testruns.
I have tried by creating rows within the database using postgres but since there's no primary key for that table I cannot do so either.

Answer (score 3):

I came into same probleme here is my solution:
Go to your project administration > Choose "Portal" > Select "Topics" > Click on "edit" for prefered view > Check your scripting tags and you'll be fine!

```
<topic id="workitems"/>

<topic id="wiki"/>
<topic id="testruns"/>
<topic id="baselines"/>
<topic id="builds"/>
<topic id="dashboard"/>
<topic id="quality"/>
<topic id="reports"/>
<topic id="monitor"/>
<topic id="global_shortcuts"/>
<topic id="project_shortcuts"/>
<topic id="user_shortcuts"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

1st check if you clicked on the expand icon at the bottom of the nav pane.
If TRs are still not there you need to enter the Administrationm view. 
There's an option called testing. In "configuration" check that testing is enabled.